# PHP count logic with bootstrap columns

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I want to count the custom fields and give the columns the right width to work with Bootstrap 3.

If there are 2 entries I want it to be:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
```

If there are 3 entries I want it to be:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
```

But it just puts the count number in each `div`.

**EDIT:** The solution of "num8er" helped me a lot, THX again! If someone finds this - this is how it works with a normal wordpress loop:

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ): ?> 

<?php $elements = []; 
while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); 
$element = get_the_title(); 
$elements[] = $element;
endwhile; 

if(sizeof($elements)>0) {
    $size = ceil(12 / sizeof($elements));
    if($columns<2) $columns = 2;
        foreach($elements AS $element) {
              echo '<div class="col-md-'.$size.'">'.$element.'</div>';
        }
    }

endif; 
?>
```

E. g. this is the DOM if i have 6 articles:

```
<div class="col-md-2"><h2>Homer Simpson’s  Guide  to  Tom Cruise</h2></div>
<div class="col-md-2"><h2>Homer Simpson’s  Guide  to  Tom Cruise</h2></div> 
...
```

Comment: You have to know the number of post ahead and then decide how many columns you need. If there are 3 posts your code will produce 4 columns `col-md-12`, `col-md-6`, `col-md-4` and `col-md-3` because you increase counter inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's collect the output to array $elements and get the size of column and wrap with it:

```
<?php if( have_rows('buehne_inhalt', 'option') ): ?>

  <h2><?=the_sub_field('subline')?></h2>
  <div class="row">
  <$php 
  $elements = []; 
  while( have_rows('buehne_inhalt', 'option') ): the_row();
    $image = get_sub_field('buehne_bild');
    $size = 'img-s';
    if( $image ) {
        $element = wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
    }

    $elements[] = $element;
  endwhile; 

  if(sizeof($elements)>0) {
    $size = ceil(12 / sizeof($elements));
    if($columns<2) $columns = 2;

    foreach($elements AS $element) {
      echo '<div class="col-md-'.$size.'">'.$element.'</div>';
    }
  }
  ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: If i use this code the "subline" is outside of the <H2> element (before the DIVs).